# How to send mails to Multiple mail ids selected dynamically using send mail task in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am using SSIS 2005 for creating package.
I am having a requirement where I need to get data from database & store it in a destination and retrieve only email ids from that store and send mails to each and every id that I have received.
I am using Expressions in the send mail task where I am getting the mail ids from the record set store. But the task is unable to retrieve all those records and showing an error as `'No recipients in the Send mail task'`.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by setting the Poperty of the send mail task 'DelayValidation to 'True'